# Receiving duplicates in T SQL Query with Case Statement

Tags: sql

I have created the following case statement to do some multiplication depending on the items sales unit of measure and for this example, even though I am declaring the SalesUoM Variable as Gallon, it is doing the math for both the gallons and the lbs.

```
 declare @SalesUOM as nvarchar(30)
 declare @drumqty as nvarchar(30)
 Set @SalesUOM = 'GAL'
 Set @drumqty = '3'

 SELECT DISTINCT 
 Case
 --- when @SalesUOM = 'DRUM' then ( @drumqty * T1.BaseQty ) 
 -- when @SalesUOM   = 'PALLET' then ( @drumqty * T4.BaseQty )
 --when @SalesUOM = 'PAIL' then ( @drumqty * T6.BaseQty )
 --when @SalesUOM  = 'TOTE' then ( @drumqty * T8.BaseQty )
 when @SalesUOM   = 'LB' then ( @drumqty * T10.BaseQty )
 When @SalesUOM = 'GAL' then (@drumQty * T12.BaseQty)
 Else '0' End as 'Item Qty'


 FROM OUGP T0  
 --INNER JOIN UGP1 T1 ON T0.[UgpEntry] = T1.[UgpEntry] 
 --INNER JOIN UGP1 T4 on T0.[UgpEntry] = T4.[UgpEntry]
 --INNER JOIN UGP1 T6 on T0.[UgpEntry] = T6.[UgpEntry]
 --INNER JOIN UGP1 T8 on T0.UgpEntry = T8.UgpEntry
 inner JOIN UGP1 T10 on T0.UgpEntry = T10.UgpEntry 
 inner JOIN UGP1 T12 on T0.UgpEntry = T12.UgpEntry
 --INNER JOIN OUOM T2 ON T0.[BaseUom] = T2.[UomEntry]
 --Inner Join OUOM T3 on T1.[UomEntry] = T3.[UomEntry] AND T3.UOMCODE in ('DR-15', 'DR-30', 'DR-55')
 --Inner Join OUOM T5 on T4.[UomEntry] = T5.[UomEntry] and T5.UOMCODE = 'PALLET'
 --left Join OUOM T7 on T6.UoMEntry = T7.UomEntry and T7.UOMCODE = 'PAIL-5'
 --left Join OUOM T9 on T8.UomEntry = T9.UomEntry AND T9.UomCode = 'TOTE'
 Left Join OUOM T11 on T10.UomEntry = T11.UomEntry and T11.UomCode = 'LB'
 Left Join OUOM T13 on T12.UomEntry = T13.UomEntry and T13.UomCode = 'GAL'
 Left join OITM on T0.UgpCode = OITM.ItemCode

 WHERE  
   OITM.ItemCode = '0000000'
```

Comment: Later, if you have a question, you'll find some useful information on how to post it here; [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are not filtering the result set on @SalesUOM in where clause or inner join.
T10 and T12 are pointing to the same table UGP1.

below are two ways that can resolve your problem
 1. Add T11.UomCode = @SalesUOM And T13.UomCode = @SalesUOM in where clause
 2. Replace below Statements 
    "Left Join OUOM T11 on T10.UomEntry = T11.UomEntry and T11.UomCode = 'LB'
    Left Join OUOM T13 on T12.UomEntry = T13.UomEntry and T13.UomCode = 'GAL'"

```
 with below statements

 Inner Join OUOM T11 on T10.UomEntry = T11.UomEntry and T11.UomCode = @SalesUOM
```

Comment: Thank you. If I make change 1, it returns no results. if I make change 2, it returns no results

Comment: Thank you. It is still returning more than one result.

Comment: "select distinct @drumqty * T10.BaseQty  
FROM OUGP T0 inner JOIN UGP1 T10 on T0.UgpEntry = T10.UgpEntry 
Inner Join OUOM T11 on T10.UomEntry = T11.UomEntry and T11.UomCode = @SalesUOM" 

The above Query should return the required result.. in fact you dont need a caes statement.